# Access VBA - create new column with first row of data

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

I apologize for the length of the post...I wanted to give you as much detail as possible. I am still an amateur to Access and still learning VBA, so be patient with me. The code is parsed together from others that I have changed to fit my needs.

**Task being performed:**

1.) I am importing several excel files from a folder into an Access table using VBA.

2.) Because the files have all the information in one column I am then segregating that column to isolate each piece of data.

**Issue:**
The first row in every excel file imported has a file reference name (ex: CA051607GA). I need to remove that as a row for each file import and would like to make it a new column that repeats on every line imported from that file. It will help me be able to track down the file later if there are issues with that record.

---

**1 Example of Import Unchanged:**

F1(<-field name)

Row1: CS16052702

Row2: 00602498878941;US1A100037;US-G8;US1A100037;US-10

Row3: 00602498878941;US1A100037;US-G8;US1A100037;US-10

---

**2 Example of Import Post Changes (macro):**

(field names for each column, but I couldn't figure out how to add a table, hence the periods to separate each field)

Row1: CS16052702

Row2: 00602498878941....US1A100037....US-G8....US1A100037....US-10

Row3: 00602498878941....US1A100037....US-G8....US1A100037....US-10

---

**3 Example of Desired Output (adding to macro):**

Row1: **CS16052702**....00602498878941....US1A100037....US-G8....US1A100037....US-10

Row2: **CS16052702**....00602498878941....US1A100037....US-G8....US1A100037....US-10

---

**Other Information:**

In case it matters I will say that obviously by nature of the macro, the files as they import come in one on top of the other. The examples above only show one file import, to demonstrate two file you would just copy the 3 lines below the original 3 lines (changing the 1st line to make it unique). I am also including the macro that I am using for your reference.

---

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Dim strFile As String 'Filename
Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
path = "C:\Users\BrooksJ\Desktop\Test\"
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset ' Moved from below

'Loop through the folder & build file list
strFile = Dir(path & "*.xls")
While strFile <> ""
'add files to the list
intFile = intFile + 1
ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
strFileList(intFile) = strFile
strFile = Dir()
Wend

'see if any files were found
If intFile = 0 Then
MsgBox "No files found"
Exit Sub
End If

'cycle through the list of files
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
filename = path & strFileList(intFile)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "Compare_Files", filename, False
Next intFile
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


'change import field name
'        CurrentDb().TableDefs("Compare_Files").Fields("F1").Name = "UPC"
'create fields to sparse out original data field
'        CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Compare_Files ADD COLUMN UPC Text;")
'        CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Compare_Files ADD COLUMN SR_Profit_Center Text;")
'        CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Compare_Files ADD COLUMN SR_Super_Label Text;")
'        CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Compare_Files ADD COLUMN SAP_Profit_Center Text;")
'        CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Compare_Files ADD COLUMN SAP_Super_Label Text;")

'Seperate data by ";" from original file
'        Const YOUR_TABLE_NAME   As String = "Compare_Files"
'        Const SQL_UPDATE_DATA   As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & "] WHERE SR_Profit_Center Is Null"
'
'        Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
'        Dim strF1Data   As String
'        Dim varData     As Variant
'
'        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL_UPDATE_DATA)
'        With rs
'            Do Until .EOF
'                strF1Data = !UPC
'                varData = Split(strF1Data, ";")
'                If UBound(varData) = 4 Then
'                    .Edit
'                    !UPC = varData(0)
'                    !SR_Profit_Center = varData(1)
'                    !SR_Super_Label = varData(2)
'                    !SAP_Profit_Center = varData(3)
'                    !SAP_Super_Label = varData(4)
'                    .Update
'                End If
'                .MoveNext
'            Loop
'            .Close
'        End With
'
'        Set rs = Nothing
'======================================================================================
CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Compare_Files ADD COLUMN UPC Text, SR_Profit_Center Text, SR_Super_Label Text, SAP_Profit_Center Text, SAP_Super_Label Text;")

CurrentDb.TableDefs("Compare_Files").Fields("F1").Name = "ref_val"

'Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim ref_val As String
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ref_val FROM Compare_Files;", dbOpenDynaset)
ref_val = rs.Fields(0).Value
rs.Close

db.Execute "DELETE FROM [Compare_Files] WHERE ref_val = '" & ref_val & "';"

Const YOUR_TABLE_NAME   As String = "Compare_Files"
Dim SQL_UPDATE_DATA   As String
SQL_UPDATE_DATA = "SELECT *, ';' & '" & ref_val & "' FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & "] WHERE SR_Profit_Center Is Null"

'Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
Dim strF1Data   As String
Dim varData     As Variant

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL_UPDATE_DATA)
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
        strF1Data = !ref_val
        varData = Split(strF1Data, ";")
        If UBound(varData) = 4 Then
            .Edit
            !ref_val = ref_val
            !UPC = varData(0)
            !SR_Profit_Center = varData(1)
            !SR_Super_Label = varData(2)
            !SAP_Profit_Center = varData(3)
            !SAP_Super_Label = varData(4)
            .Update
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

Set rs = Nothing
'==========================================================================================
End Sub
```

---

Some of the code will not capture within the code boxes, so I tried to isolate the code the best that I could. Let me know if you need me to change how it reads to make it more understandable.

**Added Notes:** The files being pulled in vary in their number of rows.

I appreciate any help or suggestions with this issue that anyone can give. If you need more information then let me know. I tried to be detailed and thorough in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty, the following adjustments will get you where you need to be for now.

First, you can simplify your `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Compare_Files ADD COLUMN UPC Text, SR_Profit_Center Text, SR_Super_Label Text, SAP_Profit_Center Text, SAP_Super_Label Text;")
```

2016-06-16 update: corrected code to capture the correct reference value and insert it in the row by row operation.

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("Compare_Files").Fields("F1").Name = "ref_val"

Const YOUR_TABLE_NAME   As String = "Compare_Files"
Dim SQL_UPDATE_DATA   As String
SQL_UPDATE_DATA = "SELECT * FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & "]"

Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
Dim varData     As Variant
Dim ref_val     As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL_UPDATE_DATA)
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
        varData = Split(!ref_val, ";")
        If UBound(varData) = 4 Then
            .Edit
            !ref_val = ref_val
            !UPC = varData(0)
            !SR_Profit_Center = varData(1)
            !SR_Super_Label = varData(2)
            !SAP_Profit_Center = varData(3)
            !SAP_Super_Label = varData(4)
            .Update
        Else
            ref_val = !ref_val
            rs.Delete
        End If

        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

Set rs = Nothing
```

As dbmitch said, there are many ways you can handle this type of problem.  If/when you have a chance, look to change your import script to process one file at a time, and externalize the loop through the files (calling the import routine once for each pass through the file list).  This opens up a whole world of pre- and post-import options to you.

The other opportunity I see would be to try to replace your row-by-row `UPDATE` with a set-based approach.  This could be an `INSERT` from the import staging table to another table, or an `UPDATE` that uses a `SELECT` that uses string manipulation functions to retrieve your delimited values.

Comment: Thanks for the help Yllzarith. I'm getting an "object required" error on the following line:

`Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ref_val FROM Compare_Files;")`

I cancelled out the separate data piece down on my original code, it looked like you had included that piece within yours.

Comment: Make sure the line `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset` has been moved up in your code as it is in my example.

Comment: I updated my code in the original post to be exactly what I have running right now. I still get the same error.

Comment: Either change all your "db." to "CurrentDB." or add a`Dim db as dao.database` and `set db = currentdb` to top of code

Comment: Yep, dbmitch has the right suggestion - I'd defined a database object that I didn't include in what I shared here.  I've corrected my code.

Comment: Thank you! It gets the job done! I will take everything both of you said about rewriting the code into consideration once the tool is complete. I just need a working model for now.

Comment: Awesome.  Sorry for the goof on my part :)!

Comment: I just noticed when I was moving on the next step that the "ref_val" is the same throughout...Is there a way to easily make this read for each file?The first line of each file imported will be different. It will not have a ";" in it. I was thinking simple, that an if no ; then fill until the next non-; line. Or to change the order that the fields are filled and make it read that the ref_val field is filled with the first line with nothing in the other fields until the next record with blank field 2, and then do the same for it. (confusing? I can update my question to include as example?)

Comment: I apologize again - I did not test my suggestion thoroughly enough.  It was not suited to capturing your reference values after all the files had been imported.

I've updated my answer with code that should do what you need now - I've tested it on a sample data set with more than one reference value this time.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem and looks like you have documented it well. I'd re-edit your question and block the top code uing the {} icon. How many lines are in the input files? There's probably a few ways to do this so as much info the better. Personally I'd pre-create an input table with the fields the way you want them named - the read all the files in storing the first line in a var, splitting the fields from remaining lines, and updating data - but it's probably faster and more efficient to import into a pre-processing table - then write an append query that updates the fields using mid$ and instr functions. That would not be as easy to error check if there was a bad file. hmmmm. a few choices.

If you havn't found an answer when I get home I'll see if I can come up with a solution. Typing is hard now

Comment: The input files can have any number of lines normally in the 1k-2k range, but sometimes less. To make sure that I understand your suggestion, you think I should create a table that has the headers already filled (outside of the macro), use the macro to pull the files into an unedited table, and then fill the pre-existing table with the data the way that I want it?

Comment: What I would do is personal preference. But if you want it to be able to handle file errors, it would be best to use code. I would definitely preset the input table with the correct field names - especially if all the data is going into one table and the field names aren't going to change. For only a couple thousand lines of few bytes each, I would read the whole file into one string variable, split it based on vbCRLF , loop on each line, splitting by ";" and then INSERT with Batch Transactions every 100 or so lines

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the INSERT with Batch Transactions every 100 or so lines piece. How would that work? Would that cause it to not show the batch name on every line?

Comment: Sorry - just a term for doing a bunch of things at once. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243806%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Once I get the tool functional, I may go back and improve it as I get time. This is more of a learn as I go project, so I appreciate the resource and personal views for how you think it would work best.